# NULL (\0) added at the end of file

Tags: linux, bash, binaryfiles

I'm trying to clean a binary file to delete all the `NULL` on it. The task is quite simple, but I found out a lot of files have a `NULL` at the end of the file and i dont know what. I'm dumping the hexadecimal value of each byte and i dont see the null anywhere, but if I do a `hexdump` of the file, I see a value `00` at the end and I dont know why.... Could be that it is a `EOF`, but it's weird becuase it doesnt appear in all files. This is the script I have, quite simpel one, it generates 100 random binary files, and then reads file per file, `char` per `char`. Following the premise that `bash` wont store `NULL`'s on variables, rewritting the `char` after storing it on a variable would avoid the `NULL`'s, but no....

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 0 100)
do
        echo "$i %"
        time dd if=/dev/urandom of=$i bs=1 count=1000
        while read -r -n 1 c;
        do
                        echo -n  "$c" >> temp
        done < $i
        mv temp $i
done
```

I also tried with:

`tr '\000' <inFile > outfile`

But same result.

This is how it looks the `hexdump` of one the files with this problem

```
00003c0 0b12 a42b cb50 2a90 1fd6 a4f9 89b4 ddb6
00003d0 3fa3 eb7e 00c4
```

`c4` should be the last byte butas you can see, there's a `00` there ....

Any clue?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that the machine where im running this is something similar like raspberry pi and the tools provided with it are quite limited.

Comment: It's called the `NUL` byte, not the `NULL` **pointer**.

Comment: That seems like a Really Bad Idea.  What kind of file is it, and why would you want to remove all the NUL bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these other commands:

```
od -tx1 inFile

xxd inFile
```

`hexdump` outputs 00 when the size is an odd number of bytes.

It seems `hexdump` without options is like `-x`, `hexdump -h` gives the list of options; `hexdump -C` may also help.

Comment: Aha, ok, I didnt know that. So looks like my problem is not here then. Thans you